# Passing empty or uninitialised STL containers by reference

Tags: c++, stl

Is it always safe to pass an empty or uninitialised STL container to a function by reference? e.g.

```
void some_function(deque<string> &passed_by_ref) {

passed_by_ref.push_back("a string");

}

int main() {

deque<string> some_data;

some_function(some_data);

return 0;

}
```

I haven't had any problems with this approach, but not sure if there could possibly be any NULL reference issues.

Comment: Rest assured, there are no null references in C++. There is some sanity in the middle of all the madness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's always safe. `deque<T>` is not a pointer type - it's an object type. The standard containers have a default constructor, so, after this statement

```
deque<string> some_data;
```

`some_data` is a correctly constructed empty `deque`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation I guess I will be careful doing it with pointers

Answer (score 2):

STL containers have default constructors, which are called in that case:

```
deque<string> some_data;
```

So the container is initialized and it's totally ok to pass a reference to it

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
   deque<string> some_data;
```

ensures that the variable `some_data` is at least initialised, as the constructor is called.

Therefore you are just passing a reference to an empty STL container - which is safe.